# Make the width of an input field relative to its content

Tags: css, wordpress, url, input

I want to display the url of the post in each post so visitors can easy share the URL. This means that the width of the input field in which the url is placed should be relative to the width of the URL.

Is it possible to make the width of an input field relative to the content (the text that is in the value="") of that input filed?

So the width of the input field must always be the same as the text that is in the field.

```
<input readonly="" type="text" onClick="this.select();" value="http://www.website.com/category/sub-category/the-post-title.html" />

input{
padding: 5px 10px;
margin: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #000;
width:auto;
```

}

For example, I've created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GB35J/
In that fiddle, you will see that the input field is to small and the whole content of that input field is not shown. When I use width: auto;, the width is to small, but when I use width:100%;, the width of the input field is way to big.

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect with an event each time the user types a character in the text field, then you can make a function that takes as a parameter the lenght of the text, and call it every time a character is typed, so it will resize accordingly the text field.

Comment: Users won't be able to type in the text field (readonly=""). The URL will automatically be shown in the input field..

Comment: Why do you want to show the URL in an input box? Just for aesthetical effect?

Comment: You could still adjust the size anyway, because you just take the variable that you use as value for the text field and send it to a function that can adjust the length. The problem is that text fields do not allow to set number of colums, but width in pixels, so if you aren't using monospace fonts, the thing would get really overly complex.

Comment: Oke I see. Well I was looking for a simple css solution. I'm not using monospace fonts and am not looking for a 'overly complex' solution so thanks anyways!

Comment: If you want an easy thing, then you can display the URL as a block element, that lets you define a background color and some padding, for example, and perhaps a border too. I'm still not much used to CSS.